# Can you setup RMM and SAP via API when creating a BU in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, sfmc-business-unit

I was curious if you can set up RMM and SAP via API? I know you can create Business units via API but I was not positive about Reply Mail Management and the Sender Auth Package.

Comment: You can definitely setup RMM via SOAP API. Documentation here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/managing_reply_mail_management_via_the_web_service_api.html. Didn't see the documentation on the SAP API, but added a Marketing-Cloud tag for more visibility.